# Node - How to reconstruct full stack trace for Promise rejection

Tags: node.js, error-handling, v8, stack-trace

I've stumbled upon an issue similar to the one discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70814419/why-does-the-stack-trace-of-an-error-that-is-returned-by-a-promise-seem-to-be-in) question but does not seem to be the same. I have a function returning a promise and rejecting (in case of errors) after a while (it's doing an HTTP call, so it takes some time). While the request is flying around the internet Node takes care of other instructions, when the request is received and the error thrown the stack trace begins from `processTicksAndRejections` (as it would for any async operations, I guess). This is a problem as I no longer have a record of where the function was called from.
So I tried the following approach, the normal code would be

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function myFunction() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    fetch('https://www.google.com').then(() => {
      return reject(new Error('Whoops!'));
    });
  });
}

myFunction().catch(console.log);
```

which prints out

```
Error: Whoops!
    at /home/dami/projects/testing/stack.js:8:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

The idea is to concatenate the old stack trace like

```
function myFunction() {
  const stack = (new Error()).stack;

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    fetch('https://www.google.com').then(() => {
      const error = new Error('Test');
      error.stack += stack;
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}

myFunction().catch(console.log);
```

which prints

```
Error: Test
    at /home/dami/projects/testing/stack.js:8:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)Error
    at myFunction (/home/dami/projects/testing/stack.js:4:18)
    at a (/home/dami/projects/testing/stack.js:16:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dami/projects/testing/stack.js:19:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

However, this does not seem the best (and most neat) solution to me, as at this point I have two 'sources' of the trace (one being the normal Node process at run_main_module, the other at processTicksAndRejections).
So the final question, is there a best practice approach to this problem?  I've tried using async/await and keeping the rejection at the top level of `myFunction`, but it will always be picked up by `processTicksAndRejections` because of its async nature. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an async function here exactly for the reason of preserving the stack trace:

```js
async function myFunction() {
    await fetch('https://www.google.com');
    throw new Error('Whoops!');
}

async function foo() {
    await myFunction();
}

async function bar() {
    await foo();
}


bar().catch(console.log);
```

Don't be bothered by the `process.processTicksAndRejections` entry in the stack trace. As long as async/await are used consistently, the whole call chain should be logged with the exception.

Comment: Solved with async/await! Thanks for the input

Comment: And if you're promisifying a callback based API, such as `.on('event', fn)` type functions? If I `reject(new Error('ded'))`, my stack trace contains no calls from before the `reject`.

Comment: @DarkNeuron Using `async` functions, promisified calls can be `await`ed like regular promises. This allows you to `throw` errors instead of `reject`ing them.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's always a good idiomatic way of doing so. I've wrapped the Node http package, which has many callbacks, which can't be awaited in a predictable fashion. Just curious as what to do in such a situation. I've made a hack similar to the OPs: `const stack = (new Error()).stack;`